# How to fix my Python tic tac toe program?

Tags: python

My code is below in Python. There is a problem with one of my equals on line 25 if anybody could suggest what I could do would help so much as well.

```
# Tic Tac Toe

import random

def drawBoard(board):
 # This function prints out the board that it was passed.

 # "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index)
   print(' | |')
   print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
   print(' | |')
   print('-----------')
   print(' | |')
   print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
   print(' | |')
   print('-----------')
   print(' | |')
   print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
   print(' | |')

def inputPlayerLetter():
 # Lets the player type which letter they want to be.
 # Returns a list with the player’s letter as the first item, and the computer's letter as the second.
   letter = ''
while=(letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
    print('Do you want to be X or O?')
    letter = input().upper()

 # the first element in the list is the player’s letter, the second is the computer's letter.
if letter == 'X':
 return ['X', 'O']
else:
 return ['O', 'X']

def whoGoesFirst():
 # Randomly choose the player who goes first.
 if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
   return 'computer'
else:
 return 'player'

def playAgain():
 # This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
     print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
     return input().lower().startswith('y')

def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter

def isWinner(bo, le):
 # Given a board and a player’s letter, this function returns True if that player has won.
 # We use bo instead of board and le instead of letter so we don’t have to type as much.
 return ((bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or # across the top
 (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or # across the middle
 (bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or # across the bottom
 (bo[7] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[1] == le) or # down the left side
 (bo[8] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[2] == le) or # down the middle
 (bo[9] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[3] == le) or # down the right side
 (bo[7] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[3] == le) or # diagonal
 (bo[9] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[1] == le)) # diagonal

def getBoardCopy(board):
 # Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
    dupeBoard = []

for i in board:
      dupeBoard.append(i)

return dupeBoard

def isSpaceFree(board, move):
 # Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
   return board[move] == ' '

def getPlayerMove(board):
 # Let the player type in their move.
   move = ' '
while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
   print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
   move = input()
   return int(move)

def chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, movesList):
 # Returns a valid move from the passed list on the passed board.
 # Returns None if there is no valid move.
    possibleMoves = []
for i in movesList:
   if isSpaceFree(board, i):
       possibleMoves.append(i)

if len(possibleMoves) != 0:
    return random.choice(possibleMoves)
else:
    return None

def getComputerMove(board, computerLetter):
 # Given a board and the computer's letter, determine where to move and
     return that move.
if computerLetter == 'X':
     playerLetter = 'O'
else:
    playerLetter = 'X'

 # Here is our algorithm for our Tic Tac Toe AI:
 # First, check if we can win in the next move
for i in range(1, 10):
    copy = getBoardCopy(board)
    if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
        makeMove(copy, computerLetter, i)
          if isWinner(copy, computerLetter):
            return i

 # Check if the player could win on their next move, and block them.
for i in range(1, 10):
     copy = getBoardCopy(board)
         if isSpaceFree(copy, i):
            makeMove(copy, playerLetter, i)
               if isWinner(copy, playerLetter):
                    return i

 # Try to take one of the corners, if they are free.
move = chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [1, 3, 7, 9])
if move != None:
    return move

 # Try to take the center, if it is free.
if isSpaceFree(board, 5):
    return 5

 # Move on one of the sides.
return chooseRandomMoveFromList(board, [2, 4, 6, 8])

def isBoardFull(board):
 # Return True if every space on the board has been taken. Otherwise
    return False.
for i in range(1, 10):
   if isSpaceFree(board, i):
     return False
        return True


print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

while True:
 # Reset the board
  theBoard = [' '] * 10
playerLetter, computerLetter = inputPlayerLetter()
turn = whoGoesFirst()
print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
gameIsPlaying = True

while gameIsPlaying:
     if turn == 'player':
 # Player’s turn.
        drawBoard(theBoard)
           move = getPlayerMove(theBoard)
                makeMove(theBoard, playerLetter, move)

if isWinner(theBoard, playerLetter):
   drawBoard(theBoard)
        print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
          gameIsPlaying = False
else:
   if isBoardFull(theBoard):
        drawBoard(theBoard)
          print('The game is a tie!')
            break

else:
   turn = 'computer'

else:
 # Computer’s turn.
   move = getComputerMove(theBoard, computerLetter)
makeMove(theBoard, computerLetter, move)

if isWinner(theBoard, computerLetter):
    drawBoard(theBoard)
print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
gameIsPlaying = False
else:
   if isBoardFull(theBoard):
      drawBoard(theBoard)
print('The game is a tie!')
break
else:
  turn = 'player'

if not playAgain():
  break
```

Comment: `while=(...)` needs to be `while(...)`

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service, a debugging service, or a homework-doing service.

Comment: Well the `inputPlayerLetter` function isn't going to work anyway because of the logic in the `while` test.  But since this seems to be homework we can leave that as an exercise for OP.  And then there are the indentation issues...

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/asweigart/my_first_tic_tac_toe), this is a similar project that may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `=` on the following line is not required. Indeed, it prohibited.

```
while=(letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
```

Try:

```
while (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
```